# Arcpy SDE Connection Getting Invalid Path?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, connection

I literally copied and pasted the file path (r'C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcCatalog\mydatabase.sde'), but after I run my script, I always get the error saying error 267, the directory name is invalid.

Comment: A `.sde` file is not a directory. It is a file. OS tools will *not* see it as an ArcGIS workspace, suitable for `ListFeatureClasses`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to access ArcSDE feature classes in feature datasets;

```
wrkspc = r"D:\Projects\DotNetDataLoader\Connection to xxx.xx.x.xxx.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = wrkspc
listds = arcpy.ListDatasets("*"):
for ds in listds:
    listfc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","",feature_dataset=ds)
    for fc in listfc:
        print fc
```

Comment: If there are feature classes outside of datasets, then you also need a `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` without a `feature_dataset` parameter. And tables without geometry would need `arcpy.ListTables`.

Comment: i think this is almost what i want, except it isn't working for me? If i only want to access sde tables, do i change the ListFeatureClasses to ListTables?

Comment: yes I think that would be best if they are non spatial tables.